# Can you explain this lambda grouping function?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, grouping

I've been using LINQ and [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) for a while, but I'm still not completely comfortable with every aspect of the feature.

So, while I was working on a project recently I needed to get a distinct list of objects based off of some property, and I ran across this code. It works, and I'm fine with that, but I'd like to understand the grouping mechanism. I don't like simply plugging code in and running away from the problem if I can help it.

Anyways the code is:

```
var listDistinct
    =list.GroupBy(
        i => i.value1,
        (key, group) => group.First()
    ).ToList();
```

In the code sample above, you're first calling `GroupBy` and passing it a lambda expression telling it to group by the property `value1`. The second section of the code is causing the confusion.

I understand that `key` is referencing `value1` in the `(key, group)` statement, but I'm still not wrapping my head around everything that's taking place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does the expression
>
> ```
> list.GroupBy(
>     i => i.value1,
>     (key, group) => group.First())
> ```
>
> do?

This creates a query which, when executed, analyzes the sequence `list` to produce a sequence of groups, and then *projects* the sequence of groups into a new sequence. In this case, the projection is to take the first item out of each group.

The first lambda chooses the "key" upon which the groups are constructed. In this case, all items in the list which have the same `value1` property are put in a group. The value that they share becomes the "key" of the group.

The second lambda projects from the sequence of keyed groups; it's as though you'd done a `select` on the sequence of groups. The net effect of this query is to choose a set of elements from the list such that each element of the resulting sequence has a different value of the `value1` property.

The documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx

If the documentation is not clear, I am happy to pass along criticisms to the documentation manager.

> This code uses `group` as the formal parameter of a lambda. Isn't `group` a reserved keyword?

No, `group` is a *contextual keyword*. LINQ was added to C# 3.0, so there might have already been existing programs using `group` as an identifier. These programs would be broken when recompiled if `group` was made a reserved keyword. Instead, `group` is a keyword only in the context of a query expression. Outside of a query expression it is an ordinary identifier.

If you want to call attention to the fact that it is an ordinary identifier, or if you want to use the identifier `group` inside a query expression, you can tell the compiler "treat this as an identifier, not a keyword" by prefacing it with `@`. Were I writing the code above I would say

```
list.GroupBy(
    i => i.value1,
    (key, @group) => @group.First())
```

to make it clear.

> Are there other contextual keywords in C#?

Yes. I've documented them all here:

http://ericlippert.com/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords/

Comment: Thank you, Eric. The documentation is fairly clear. Am I understanding then that "group" used in the scenario above isn't a reserved word and I can pass in more descriptive name for that lambda? That helps quite a bit - I was tripping up thinking that group was a reserved word for this operation, but knowing otherwise makes it a bit more obvious as to what is happening.

Comment: Also, you are a boss, sir.

Comment: @elucid8: I'll update my answer to address your second question.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the thoughtful response. This really does clear things up wonderfully!

Answer (score 4):

I would like to simplify this to a list of `int` and how to do distinct in this list by using `GroupBy`:

```
var list = new[] {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3};
```

if you call `GroupBy` with `x => x`, you will get 3 groups with type:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>

{{1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3}}
```

The key of each group are: 1, 2, 3. And then, when calling `group.First()`, it means you get first item of each group:

```
{1,1}: -> 1.
{2,2,2}: -> 2
{3,3} -> 3
```

So the final result is : `{1, 2, 3}`

Your case is similar with this.

Answer (score 2):

It uses [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) of the `Enumerable.GroupBy` method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
   this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
   Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
   Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

which, as stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx):

> Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function and creates a result value from each group and its key.

So, unlike [other overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341740.aspx) which return a bunch of groups (i.e. `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TK, TS>>`), this overload allows you to project each group to a single instance of a `TResult` of your choice.

Note that you could get the same result using the basic `GroupBy` overload and a `Select`:

```
var listDistinct = list
    .GroupBy(i => i.value1)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(key, group) => group.First()
```

It's just taking the `First()` element within each group.

Within that lambda expression `key` is a key that was used to create that group (`value1` in your example) and `group` is `IEnumerable<T>` with all elements that has that `key`.

Answer (score 0):

The below self describing example should help you understand the grouping:

```
class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create some items
        var item1 = new Item {Value = 0, Text = "a"};
        var item2 = new Item {Value = 0, Text = "b"};
        var item3 = new Item {Value = 1, Text = "c"};
        var item4 = new Item {Value = 1, Text = "d"};
        var item5 = new Item {Value = 2, Text = "e"};

        // Add items to the list
        var itemList = new List<Item>(new[] {item1, item2, item3, item4, item5});

        // Split items into groups by their Value
        // Result contains three groups.
        // Each group has a distinct groupedItems.Key --> {0, 1, 2}
        // Each key contains a collection of remaining elements: {0 --> a, b} {1 --> c, d} {2 --> e}
        var groupedItemsByValue = from item in itemList
                                  group item by item.Value
                                  into groupedItems
                                  select groupedItems;

        // Take first element from each group: {0 --> a} {1 --> c} {2 --> e}
        var firstTextsOfEachGroup = from groupedItems in groupedItemsByValue
                                    select groupedItems.First();

        // The final result
        var distinctTexts = firstTextsOfEachGroup.ToList(); // Contains items where Text is: a, c, e
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice example, but this question is about the lamda `GroupBy` method

Comment: @PhilippM: In order to clear the thought up I decided to change illegible and concise *GroupBy* syntax into readable and verbose syntax of LINQ queries. Just to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's equvilant to

```
var listDistinct=(
    from i in list
    group i by i.value1 into g
    select g.First()
    ).ToList();
```

The part `i => i.value1` in your original code is **key selector**. In this code, is simply `i.value` in the syntax of *group elements by **key***.

The part `(key, group) => group.First()` in the original code is a delegate of **result selector**. In this code, it is wrote in a more semantical syntax of *from ... select*. is Here `g` is `group` in original code.